# this.unblock in a method if the method is non-blocking

Tags: javascript, meteor

I would like to know if I need to use `this.unblock()` inside a Meteor method if the method is already non-blocking.

Here is a contrived example:

```
Meteor.methods({
  myMethod() {
    this.unblock();

    someAPIWrapper(params, function (err, res) {
      // do something with res asynchronously
    });
  }
});
```

`myMethod` makes an HTTP call using some node.js wrapper for a third party API. It is asynchronous.

In this case, is there a performance gain by using `this.unblock()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically no.

[`this.unblock()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/method_unblock) allows the execution of ordered method calls from a single client to continue within a new fiber because the current one is blocked by a synchronous operation.

So as long as your method body does not do any work that blocks the current fiber, you don't need to unblock it explicitly. In fact, it *may* even cause its own overhead due to creation of new unnecessary fibers.